# Is there a standard for Java Keystore PKCS#12?

Tags: java, cryptography, keystore, pkcs#12

I am working on a project feature where users can upload their PKCS#12 file to be used as a certificate identity for the service running in the cloud.

Once, I started reading rfc7292 "PKCS #12: Personal Information Exchange Syntax v1.1", I noticed that the standard was more general than the impression I got from working with Java keystores.

For example, Java expects the server certificate to be in the first bag while the standard states no such requirement (also, encrypting the whole content with a password).

Is there a JSR describing the behavior of Java keystore ?

Comment: I haven't found a JSR for it. Java's PKCS#12 support has been changing since it was first introduced in Java 6. Therefore, what is actually supported may vary depending on exactly which version of Java you are targeting, e.g. [JEP 229](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/jdk9-keytool-transitions-default-keystore-to-pkcs12)